# Bug: m_rect.IsRectEmpty() triggers an ASSERT when pixel right is 645..700?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have an awkward ASSERT in MFC CMemDC:

```
CMemDC::CMemDC(CDC& dc, const CRect& rect) :
    m_dc(dc), m_bMemDC(FALSE), m_hBufferedPaint(NULL), m_pOldBmp(NULL), m_rect(rect)
{
    ASSERT(!m_rect.IsRectEmpty());

    HDC hdcPaint = NULL;
    :
    :
 }
```

All seems works correct.
But if the CRect parameter rect contains this value (0,0,700,0) I get an ASSERT!
With pixel right > 701 or < 640 not!

Can anyone explain or confirm this?

---

Remark: I should maybe add this: The `CMemDC` here is from "afxcontrolbarutil.h".
It is not CMemDC from Keith Rule.

Comment: I don't remember which of the values are the height and which is the width, but why do you create a rectangle without width (or height)?

Comment: And [the `CRect::IsRectEmpty` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class?view=msvc-170#isrectempty) very clearly states that a rectangle with zero (or negative) width or height is considered "empty".

Comment: I have tested this, and do not see any difference when setting the third value (right), regardless of value, be it 600,700,701 etc, as expected I see assert triggered everytime.

Comment: `CRect::IsRectEmpty()` calls the Win32 `IsRectEmpty()` function - it's in the atlypes.h header. According to the Win32 documentation, _An empty rectangle is one that has no area; that is, the coordinate of the right side is less than or equal to the coordinate of the left side, or the coordinate of the bottom side is less than or equal to the coordinate of the top side._ So, if it doesn't work as specified there, then it's a Windows bug...

Comment: I see this behaviour in Debug Mode. I don't create the rectangle myself. I tested this in the debugger, with this value. tagRECT.right = 700, all other rect parameter =0. I can this alwayas provoqe in the Debugger

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: @TomTom a the behaviour you observe is normal. A rectangle with zero height is considered empty.

Comment: _"With pixel right > 701 or < 640 not!"_: please don't describe your code but show it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your respones.
The problem was somewhere else entirely.

I ran into a GDI objects overflow (>10'000 GDI objects), observed Windows Task Manager in the GDI Objects column.
This was the reason why I had this weird, unexpected behavior in the debugger.
After removing the GDI object leak (missing delete the previous CBrush objects in OnCtlColor) all works now fine.

--

```
void CColorCheckBoxText::SetBackgroundColor(COLORREF AColor)
{
    if (mBackgroundColorBrush)
        DeleteObject(mBackgroundColorBrush);
    mBackgroundColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(AColor);
    Invalidate();
}

HBRUSH CColorCheckBoxText::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    :
    return mBackgroundColorBrush;  // color for the empty area of the control
}
```

Comment: There is quite literally **not a single reason ever** to call `delete` in C++. Replace all your calls to `delete` with appropriate pointer types, and there will not be a resource leak ever again.

Comment: Interesting "Replace all your calls to delete with appropriate pointer types":  This is new for me,  Can you show me a short code example,  I did look in [link](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/refactor-into-uniqueptr/).  But not sure, if you mean this.

Comment: Any of the Standard C++ [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers) types will do. The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) has a number of pre-implemented template instantiations specific to Windows programming (see [RAII resource wrappers](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers)).

Comment: Looks cool the Window Implementation Library, I was not aware of this. I have added code for my example, I am not sure how to use it now , to avoid `DeleteObject`